# Can Windows 10TP be installed without replacing or modifying the existing Windows installation?

Tags: windows-7, installation, external-hard-drive, windows-10-preview

Some documentation indicates that Win 10TP can be installed fresh on an empty partition. Other documentation seems to describe that it must replace an existing Windows installation and/or that it will destroy an existing installation.

I don't want the existing Windows touched. Can the installation be done fresh, from scratch, on an empty partition (external drive), with no effect whatsoever on the existing Windows installation?

Beyond the existing Windows installation, would installation of Win 10TP on an external hard drive change anything other than the hard drive on which it is loaded (e.g., modify the BIOS, BIOS settings, or anything else outside of the external drive)?

Comment: install it into a VHD to avoid any changes: http://hyrokumata.blogspot.de/2014/10/installing-windows-10-technical-preview.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the point of your installation of win10TP? If it's just for researching of the new wins maybe you should consider using a vmware player or hyper-v virtual machines..?

If there is any better reason **your best bet** is to disconnect/disable(in BIOS) all the other drives while installing the win10 on external drive. That way nothing will be touched by win10 but you'll have to play with *quick boot bios menu* when you want to start the win10.. and the windows installations won't know about each other so you will control via bios which one will the pc boot.

You can also use the vhd as someone mentioned earlier.
If you choose not to disconnect your primary drive, and make dual boot like [this one](http://blog.laptopmag.com/dual-boot-windows-10-preview) it will definitely change your bootloader config because your primary OS has to know where the second OS is.

Comment: Full support is ending for Win 7 and Microsoft is offering a free upgrade to Win 10 (http://thenextweb.com/microsoft/2015/01/21/windows-10-will-free-upgrade-windows-7-8-8-1-users/).  I wanted to give it a thorough evaluation in a real-life environment to test the user interface and features as well as compatibility with everything that I keep Win 7 around for.  I could start with a VM, but there are usually limits running in that mode that might require an actual installation to test.  I like your idea of disconnecting the internal drive for installation.